# How to add more images horizontally to existing gallery using elemontor

Tags: plugins, images, media-library, gallery

I deleted all my unattached images from media as I had so many copies not being used and now I'm missing all my images in my gallery.
The grid is already there so it should only be to upload add the images again (Im using elementor and Im a beginner). I can only add images on top of each other, I had 3 images side by side. I cant figure out how to add the other images. If I select 3 images that I want in a row they end up on top of each other and when I try to drag them up the gallery changes and the size of images are changing too.
Please hope someone can help me [image]